# LED backlit monitor suitable for documents/web?

Tags: display, led, backlight

I am looking to buy a 24" monitor. Sometimes I watch movies, but mostly it will be for document editing and programming (Visual Studio). I have found a product I like, and it has an 'LED backlit' model and a standard model for about the same price.

I have read that backlit displays have advantages, but could they be too bright/high contrast for working with text?

(Note I'm not looking for shopping recommendations - just advice on how 'backlit' monitors display text.)

Comment: Is this question about LED/non-LED monitors or about monitors which use LED backlight with LEDs on the edge of the screen and lightguides versus monitors which actually have LEDs behind the screen?

Comment: @AndrejaKo It's the [BenQ G2420HD](http://benq.co.uk/products/LCD/index.cfm/product/1098) vs [BenQ G2420HDBL](http://benq.co.uk/products/LCD/index.cfm/product/1157).

Comment: That makes it then a question about LED/non-LED monitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, 'regular' LCD monitors use one or two cold cathode lamps for backlighting - these tend to be somewhat bigger and use more power. LEDs tend to provide brighter, more even lighting, and probably should last longer (They're simpler, needing no inverter, and use a lot of smaller lamps rather than one large one) .Taking into account that you can adjust and display brightness, the LED is probably a better choice. Just remember to adjust settings to your liking with both the monitor, and the system - for example tweaking cleartype.